# How to reset navigation stack each time Tab Bar item is selected?

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

So, i need to reset navigation stack each time a tab is selected from the tab navigation.
Right now it works like this:

User is on Tab A -> Opened New Screen (i.e. News) on Tab A -> Selected Tab B -> **Selected Tab A and came back to last opened screen (News) instead of coming back to Tab A .**

I need to change the last step and reset the opened screens each time user selects new Tab.

i know that there are few API items that i can use for it, like `pop`, `popToRoot` and `resetTo` but i have no idea how to use it correctly.

Can someone give me an example that i can use it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Listen](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=listening-to-tab-selected-events) to `BottomTabSelected` event and call `this.props.navigator.popToRoot`.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering. I wanted to follow up: is it possible to reset the stack with `popToRoot` to the certain tab?

Comment: In v2 you can pop to a specific component using [popTo](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/screen-api?id=poptocomponentid-mergeoptions)